# How to use a separate node container in your ddev setup?

Tags: ddev

Sometimes you want to use a custom node version in your ddev setup. I will give an example configuration how this can be archived.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file in `.ddev` folder named `docker-compose.node.yaml` with the following content:

```
version: '3.6' 
services:
  node:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-node
    image: node:10.6
    user: "node"
    restart: "no"
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.platform: ddev
      com.ddev.app-type: php
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
    volumes:
      - "../:/var/www/html:cached"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Ddev will start a separate node container that is not terminated after startup.
You can ssh into that container using the command `ddev ssh -s node`

You can also configure post-start hook like this:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec-host: ddev exec -s node npm ci --quiet
    - exec-host: ddev exec -s node npm start
```

Comment: Could you please edit this so the docker-compose version is 3.6? Thanks. ddev v1.1.1 has moved on with the docker-compose version.

Comment: With DDev v1.11.1, I tried this and got the following message on `ddev start`: "The DDEV_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string." Should I use something else for `com.ddev.app-url`?

Comment: I removed obsolete DDEV_URL.